# how to blur the background video of the targeted div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I realize there have been numerous questions regarding how to make the background image blurred, but i was wondering if it's possible to blur the background video of the targeted div, using either css or jquery(blur js) plugin.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/blur-js

currently,the plugin only supports the .body source, so there's no way of targeting any other div other than inserting the image i want to blur to the background of the 'body'

or, as a second method, if i give filter blur by using this js plugin 
http://nbartlomiej.github.io/foggy/

it blurs text, not the background of the layer.

see how it blurs text, not the background.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eEjT.jpg

could anyone help me figure out how to blur the background video?

here is my website that contains moving video. thanks.

http://lifeto.cafe24.com/xe/index.php?mid=today

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.vid-container{
  position:relative;
  height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.bgvid{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100vw;
}
.inner-container{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  position:absolute;
  top:calc(50vh - 200px);
  left:calc(50vw - 200px);
  overflow:hidden;
}
.bgvid.inner{
  top:calc(-50vh + 200px);
  left:calc(-50vw + 200px);
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf9,<svg%20version='1.1'%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter%20id='blur'><feGaussianBlur%20stdDeviation='10'%20/></filter></svg>#blur");
  -webkit-filter:blur(10px);
  -ms-filter: blur(10px);
  -o-filter: blur(10px);
  filter:blur(10px);
}
.box{
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  font-family:Helvetica;
  color:#fff;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
  padding:30px 0px;
}
.box h1{
  text-align:center;
  margin:30px 0;
  font-size:30px;
}
.box input{
  display:block;
  width:300px;
  margin:20px auto;
  padding:15px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  color:#fff;
  border:0;
}
.box input:focus,.box input:active,.box button:focus,.box button:active{
  outline:none;
}
.box button{
  background:#2ecc71;
  border:0;
  color:#fff;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:20px;
  width:330px;
  margin:20px auto;
  display:block;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.box button:active{
  background:#27ae60;
}
.box p{
  font-size:14px;
  text-align:center;
}
.box p span{
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#666;
}
```

```html
<div class="vid-container">
  <video class="bgvid" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" preload="auto" loop>
      <source src="http://mazwai.com/system/posts/videos/000/000/109/webm/leif_eliasson--glaciartopp.webm?1410742112" type="video/webm">
  </video>
    <div class="box">
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Password"/>
      <button>Login</button>
      <p>Not a member? <span>Sign Up</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: um... i don't see anything??!